# Degree of field extension $[\mathbb{Q}(i,2^{\frac{1}{4}}):\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{4}})]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am solving a problem where I need to find the splitting field and its degree of $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. During the computation, I need to calculate the degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(i,2^{\frac{1}{4}}):\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{4}})]$.

I think the degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(i,2^{\frac{1}{4}}):\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{4}})]$ should be 4 as $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}})$ and thus irreducible and [$\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}}):\mathbb{Q}$] is degree 4.

Why is degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(i,2^{\frac{1}{4}} ):\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{4}})] = 2$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $i$ is a root of $x^2+1$ and $x^2+1$  is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}})$

Answer (score 2):

The degree is at most $2$ because $i$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

The degree cannot be $1$ because $\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{4}})$ is real and $i$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

All the powers of $i$ are obtainable as $Q$-linear combination of $1$ and $i$, so the extension has degree 2.

And be careful, the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}})$ is $x^2+1$ which has degree 2, which is just another way to prove what said above.